# Stretch the last element in UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, uistackview

I have vertical `UIStackView` which has two horizontal `UIStackViews`, if bottom `UIStackView` has larger width than `UIStackView` on the top then `UIStackView` on the top will be stretched to the width of the bottom `UIStackView`.

And now I have first element in the top `UIStackView` stretched, but I want to stretch last element.

Current:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Not really clear what you want... Is the "outer" stack view a fixed width? Or does it stretch based on the length of "gtfdgsd..."? Is the bottom row two Buttons? Is the left Button a fixed-width? Or is it supposed to stretch? Or does it have a fixed left-right padding? You want both top-row labels to stretch based on content? What should happen if combined width of the two labels exceeds the width of the bottom row?

Comment: @DonMag thanks for your comment. Outer stack view is stretch based on constraints. Yes, bottom stack has two buttons. Doesn't matter what bottom stack has, because I just want next simple behavior: Now, my first label fill all available space in the top stack, and all others labels fit to content, but I want last label to fill all available space, and all others(include first) fit to content, as it on the second picture.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming your labels have the default Horizontal `Content Hugging Priority` set to 251 each, change the Green Label to 252

[image]

Everything else you should be able to leave as you have it.